# How do I get data from my stream and work with it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, flutter-test

I have stored the following data in Cloud Firestore:[image]

I also have a stream that checks the data.

```
class StufenService {
  String userID;
  StufenService(this.userID);
  
  
  final CollectionReference userTodos =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');
  
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStufe() {
    var stufe = userTodos.where('Stufe', isEqualTo: 1);
    stufe = stufe.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID);
    return stufe.snapshots();
  }}
```

I use the stream in a StreamBuilder:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 112, 192, 1),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: standard(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: stufenService.getStufe(),
                    builder:
                        (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                      if (snapshot == ({'Stufe', 1})) {
                        return ToDo1F();} else
                      return ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            );
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          itemCount: Stufen.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext, i) {
                            String key = Stufen.keys.elementAt(i);
                            return StufenItem(
                              key,
                              Stufen[key]!,
                              () => toggleDone(key),
                              () => select(key),
                            );
                          });
                    },
                  );
                }
              }));
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, I cannot return the data of the stream.
I try it here:

```
if (snapshot.data == ({'Stufe', 1})) {
                        return ToDo1F();}
```

I don’t think that’s the way to go. Does anyone know how to do that? Is there something else wrong?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi ..So you want to display document data for userTodos in ListView ?

Comment: @AsimJawad there ist no error. When I select a Stufe (= Level) in the ListView, I want the Stream to recognise this and return the page I've assigned to the Level the User has selected

Comment: @Garth I want the Stream to watch 'Stufe:int' (= Level:int) and return a different page, wenn die Level number changes. `if (snapshot.data == ({'Stufe', 1})) {
                        return ToDo1F();}` For example, if level:1 is stored in the user’s document, the stream should return ToDoF1 ().

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you're data structure from your Firestore DB . Seems like you just want to retrieve document data from your Stream .

For that :

**UPDATED**

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 500,
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: db.collection('userTodos').snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.data!.docs[0]['Stufe'] == '1') {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => GotoDesiredScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                    if (snapshot.data!.docs[0]['Stufe'] == '2') {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => GotoDesiredScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                    if (snapshot.data!.docs[0]['Stufe'] == '3') {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => GotoDesiredScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text('select');
                    }
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('Loading ...'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if this is all you wanted from for Stream

Comment: I want to check the specific ’Stufe: int = (level: int) in the document of the respective user. For different levels, I have prepared different pages that the stream should play when the user selects a level. In my code above, I just checked if level 1 is included in the snapshot to see if it works. But it doesn’t.

Comment: In ListView there are only buttons that allow the user to select level 1, 2 or 3. If he does so, the new level is stored in the document of the respective user. I want the stream to automatically switch to the page I have assigned to the selected level.

Comment: @Lars I see ...Will update answer shorlty then

Comment: That looks great! I've edited my code your way. One Problem remains. I get the following error: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0` I think its about the zero in here: `snapshot.data!.docs[0]['Stufe']`. Two questions. 1. What do I have to change? 2. What does `Doc[0]` do? I understand everything but this.

Comment: If you don't know what to do, that's okay. Just tell me what docs[0] does.

Comment: Maybe the stream does return no data. I've shared the stream, could you take a look at it? Maybe there is something wrong...

Comment: @Lars Hi Sorry for late response . Can you please share your code . the Doc[0] is indexed element . So it would display the first element . Did you map the data?

Comment: I can share the code, but you have to be more specific. Which code should i share? What do you mean by 'Did you map the data?' I’ll try to get you everything you need!

Comment: Do you mean this: `Map<String, dynamic> level = snapshot.data! as Map<String, dynamic>;` By asking, if I map the data? Unfortunately I get the following error by this code: `type '_JsonQuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`